# does the webpack DefinePlugin rewrite library code that is in node_modules?

Tags: webpack

Does the webpack DefinePlugin rewrite library code that is in node_modules?

I am publishing frontend npm modules that contain environment vars that should be injected when consumed in a larger build. Currently, it only injects the app, not my node_modules libs.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found...

I needed to turn off the node process mock that webpack was creating.

add the following to your webpack config

```
{
  node: {
    process: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question! I've been trying to solve this for the past few hours and this was the only relevant Google result for "webpack defineplugin on libraries". I have no idea how I would have solved it otherwise.